# Using nginx cannot complete acme-challange / access files in new locations

Tags: nginx

I would like my flask app to be an api eventually, and run it off a windows server. I own a domain on google domains, I added a DNS of api.(mydomain) using the IP address of the computer that it will run off of as a server. I wanted to get the api to be ssl and https and have been using waitress -> nginx -> win-acme

Here is my directory: C:\Users\Wreck\Documents\Flask\acme-challenge
,  Within this folder i made a test.txt with just pure text.

In the Flask folder, I have a flask app that for right now just prints hello world.

My first step is starting waitress:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Wreck\Documents\Flask>waitress-serve --listen=*:5000 flaskappv1:app
INFO:waitress:Serving on http://[::]:5000
INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

Hello world! displays on localhost.

Then I set up nginx, after hours of testing, I am still completely stuck as to why returning the text file from acme-challenge still produces an error. Here is my code:

```
error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_tokens off;
    
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.rootmusic.app;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root C:/Users/Wreck/Documents/Flask/acme-challenge/;
            allow all;
            default_type "text/plain";
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my outputs:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl http://api.rootmusic.app/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.txt
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl http://api.rootmusic.app/
Hello World!
```

I have turned off windows defender. I have port-fowarded from my server computer's ip port 80 and 5000. I have also set inbound permissions for windows firewall for port 80 and 5000.

I think it might be something with my permissions to read and view, but in task manager nginx runs off of Wreck which is me and im pretty sure is an admin user and i checked perms for read and write for the whole file structure.

If this is helpful this is the error I receive when I tried to use win-acme to get HTTPS for api.(domain)

```
 Plugin Manual generated source api.rootmusic.app with 1 identifiers
 Plugin Single created 1 order
 Cached order has status invalid, discarding
 [api.rootmusic.app] Authorizing...
 [api.rootmusic.app] Authorizing using http-01 validation (SelfHosting)
 [api.rootmusic.app] Authorization result: invalid
 [api.rootmusic.app] {"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized","detail":"(my ip): Invalid response from http://api.rootmusic.app/.well-known/acme-challenge/uQdTJeSYMKLUy9_7dIgEzLZQUay11eYUxvKNcxNPPv4: 404","status":403,"instance":null}
 [api.rootmusic.app] Deactivating pending authorization
```

As you may have guessed I am pretty new to system admin. But thank you for reading this far. If you have suggestions on switching programs or any way to do this easier, let me know, because I am completely stuck. I started with IIC but switched to nginx because I couldnt figure it out.

But yea, why is nginx not able to read files in the acme-challenge location? I assume that is what is also stopping win-acme.